# Not getting full float division for values above 1. in python 3.6.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, floating-point, division

I am trying to fill a `np.zeros` 2d array with some values and then normalize those values with the max value in each row.

I am dividing each value of that row with the max value using the `max()` function. Although I am getting proper float division for values in the array up to the max value, Python only returns `1.` for values after the max value in the array.

How can can I have proper values in this case?

I am using Python 3.6.2 with jupyter notebook.

```
 import numpy as np
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf) #for printing full array

 l1 = np.zeros((5,10))
 l2 = np.arange(500)

 for j in range(len(l1[:,0])):
  for i in range(len(l1[0,:])):
    if i<(j+(len(l1[0,:])/2)):
        l1[j,i] = l1[j,i-1]+1
    if i>(j+(len(l1[0,:])/2)-1):
        l1[j,i] = l1[j,i-1]-1


for j in range(len(l1[:,0])):
 for i in range(len(l1[0,:])):
    l1[j,i] = l1[j,i]/(max(l1[j,:]))

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,25))
ax.imshow(l1)
ax.set_aspect('5')

print(l1[0,:])
```

The result I get is:

```
[0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0. ]
```

The array without normalizing:

```
[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 4. 3. 2. 1. 0.]
```

Comment: Why should a normalized array contain values larger than 1?

Comment: Can you please make a shorter example (like, 10 values instead of 500) and show what result you expected to get?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that the max *changes* as you edit the array.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks I have edited my error in the description.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks, indeed yes. That seems to be the problem. I will try then to make the code properly.

Comment: Why is there barely in whitespace in the first loops? The indentation seems different from the second snippet, too.

Comment: @AMC That was because I ad copy pasted the code and manually added the indents. But now you can see the solution code that I have added and you will see proper indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user2357112supportsMonica and mkrieger1 I found my mistake in the code. The max value was changing as the for loops edit the array. The solution to this was achieved by changing the code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf) #for printing full array

l1 = np.zeros((10,20))
l2 = np.arange(500)

for j in range(len(l1[:,0])):
    for i in range(len(l1[0,:])):
        if i<(j+(len(l1[0,:])/2)):
            l1[j,i] = l1[j,i-1]+1
        if i>(j+(len(l1[0,:])/2)-1):
            l1[j,i] = l1[j,i-1]-1

for j in range(len(l1[:,0])):
    l1[j,:] = l1[j,:]/(max(l1[j,:]))

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,25))
ax.imshow(l1)
ax.set_aspect('1')
```